# Python. Libtcodpy. Linux (Lubuntu) Attribute Error

Tags: python, libtcod

I've had to fight to get this library to run. I can import it and the samples_cpp works fine. But when I run my roguelike, I get this error:

```
> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import libtcodpy as libtcod
  File "/home/slumking/Documents/Python/scripts/hm_game-master/libtcodpy.py", line 479, in <module>
    _lib.TCOD_console_has_mouse_focus.restype = c_bool
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: ./libtcod.so: undefined symbol: TCOD_console_has_mouse_focus
```

Comment: The function `TCOD_console_has_mouse_focus()` was added in version 1.5.2 of `libtcod`. Which version is installed on your system?

Comment: 1.5.1 
I thought that was the latest..
I can't find 1.5.2. It just says 'work in progress' on the site.

Comment: Then you maybe should downgrade your Python wrapper to one that wraps the stable version 1.5.1 instead of 1.5.2.

Comment: Do you mean my python version?
How would one go about doing that?

Comment: No not the Python version, the version of _libtcodpy.py_. That module obviously needs `libtcod` 1.5.2. Maybe there is an older version of the module for version 1.5.1.